# Redirect after validation fails in symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony, redirect

I would separate logic in my controllers.

In `newWebsiteAction()` I display my form. Next, I send data from form to `postWebsiteAction()` method.

If validation fails, I would like to redirect to `senWebsiteAction()` and display errors. What I should add to my code to do it? Because now I dont see errors

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use AppBundle\Entity\Website;
    use AppBundle\Form\Type\WebsiteType;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    class WebsitesController extends Controller
    {
    /**
     * @Route("/websites", name="websites")
     */
    public function getWebsiteAction()
    {

        return $this->render('websites/index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/websites/new", name="websites.new")
     */
    public function newWebsiteAction()
    {
        $website = new Website();

        $form = $this->createForm(new WebsiteType(), $website);

        return $this->render('websites/create.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/websites/post", name="websites.post", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function postWebsiteAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $website = $form->getData();
            $website->setUser($this->getUser());

            $em =$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($website);

            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('websites');
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('websites.new');
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. IMHO you doing it wrong.

First: Why you wan't to do it in single action? If you want some separation better move some logic to services. Because store logic in services is Symfony2 way. E.g. Persist and flush logic to some EntityManager service (abstract example).

Second (hint): How you will get $form errors in `newWebsiteAction()`?

Edit:

Here is how I usually doing that:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $form = $this->createForm('post', $post);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $em->persist($post);
         $em->flush();

         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('show_post', ['slug_title' => $post->getSlugTitle()]));
    }
    return $this->render('GeekhubMainBundle:Post:create.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

yes it looks like some logic will duplicated in different methods, but:

1) If method less than 20 lines all fine;

2) In your way you methods for handle form or create entity are not reusable;

Hope that will help :)

Comment: Could you show me, what is the best practice for doing this ?

Comment: @PawelBrzoski, Iook to answer

Answer (score -2):

```
public function postWebsiteAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $website = $form->getData();
        $website->setUser($this->getUser());

        $em =$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($website);

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('websites');
    } else {
        $this->generateUrl('\your_defined_route');
        return $this->redirect($url);
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('websites.new');
}
```

check out the else after $form is valid.

Comment: He is already doing this. If you pay more attention you will notice that if form validation fail, he is redirecting to `websites.new` route, which is the one that creates the form.